# Understand a German employment visa rejection

Tags: working-visas, germany, employment, paperwork

I am a non-EU national (Ecuador). I've been working in the EU (not in Germany) for the past 3 years as a risk analyst. I hold a BA from the UK and a MSc from Italy.

I received a job offer from a Fintech in Cologne as a Risk Analyst.  The salary is €44,000 gross annually.

Unfortunately, after applying for the employment visa, the outcome is a rejection, and I truly don't understand the reason, although it is stated in the letter.

*Leider konnte diese Genehmigung durch die zuständige Arbeitsagentur nicht auf der Grundlage des 39 (2) 1 Nr. 1 Residence Act erteilt werden, da die Zahlung der Beschäftigung als Risikoanalyst nicht den Standardtarifen / örtlichen Bedingungen entspricht.
Aufgrund fehlender Einwilligung kann kein Visum ausgestellt werden, daher muss Ihr Antrag abgelehnt werden.*

As far as I understand, it is regarding the salary, but I can't find information on what is required.

Could any of you share an input of what went wrong? and perhaps what conditions have not been met and what to do to amend it?

Comment: Sounds like your occupation doesn't qualify as shortage occupation which means the minimum salary requirement for you would be 55,200 EUR. https://www.fragomen.com/insights/alerts/minimum-salary-level-increase-3. It would be best if your employer call job center. They are usually helpful and would explain you the problem.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it means "not in Germany." I will edit.

Comment: Is it the first time your employer is recruiting in this position from abroad? It seems they should have an idea of what counts as an acceptable salary in the area. They can amend this by giving you a higher offer of course!

Comment: @VarunAgw That's good advice. Technically, those are the minimum salary requirements for an EU Blue Card under § 18b (2). If they are not met, it's still possible to get a residence permit under § 18b (1) but only with a permission from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit*.

Comment: @Relaxed From my understanding, ZAV only gives approval for specialized shortage occupation.

Comment: @VarunAgw I don't know, it sounds possible I don't have precise statistics at hand. The point I was making is one of legal reasoning. My understanding is that everything you describe (including the “shortage occupation” concept) is the procedure under § 18b (2) to obtain an EU Blue Card. Legally, it's still possible to get a residence permit under § 18b (1), at least in theory. It's only in this case that § 39 and the evaluation mentioned by the OP kick in.

Comment: @Nicolas What kind of details are you expecting? It's inconvenient but pretty straightforward, risk analysts typically earn more and it's forbidden for you and your employer to agree on a lower pay.

Comment: @Relaxed - well at this point is up to the company. At the moment I imagine they are consulting an expert, something perhaps they should have done at the beginning. Regarding the salary, the embassy shared the required amount (48k). So i don't expect much, solution is pretty simple, I either get a new contract with the required salary, or I don't. Plus, considering you comments below, I agree, situation leave people stranded in the middle of nowhere. Plus, 44k give or take is not a bad salary anywhere... so I agree there is a degree of discrimination... personally I think unfair.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the salary offered by your prospective employer is deemed too low compared to the local standard for similar occupations by the relevant *Arbeitsagentur*. The law cited, “§ 39 (2) 1 Nr. 1 Residence Act” is meant to protect local workers (citizens and current residents) against competition from newcomers accepting less attractive work conditions.

As mentioned in a comment, another route to a German residence permit is the EU Blue Card under § 18b (2). If you meet its salary requirements (currently €55,200 gross per year), no permission from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit* is required and the authorities would have no discretion in evaluating the conditions of your employment.

Either way, the most obvious solution is to get an offer with a higher salary. Alternatively, if the employer is not willing to move and has strong evidence this salary really is fair, maybe the evaluation can be disputed in court? However, it's difficult to see how that could work in practice. I know next to nothing about this industry but note that a quick search on Google reveals (through gehalt.de and stepstone.de) that typical salaries are indeed significantly higher (by at least €10k).

Comment: Any employer who don't want to pay you fairly is not likely to fight for you in the court.

Comment: @VarunAgw I wouldn't expect the employer to fight much either. The employee is the one with standing here anyway, what the employer could do is provide some information. All that assumes that the employer does not, in fact, pay unfairly, otherwise going to court is a non-starter. At the end of the day, I really mention this for completeness's sake, as indicated I don't think it's a realistic option.

Comment: @VarunAgw I edited the answer to use stronger wording.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The relevant portion of the rejection is (translated) : **because the payment of employment as a risk analyst does not meet standard tariffs / local conditions**

Comment: I would just add that the OP requested to know what the minimum salary is, but such information is not published and determined by civil servants at a local level based on local conditions.  As such, then it could be that a salary of xx might be sufficient for the job in location yy but not in location zz.

Comment: My 5 cents so that it is easier to understand the logic of rejection. The reason is not that you got a low salary. The reason is that the employer tried to offer a position with low salary, which usually will not be accepted by locals. Therefore, the employer tried to higher somebody from abroad, and by this means, tried to lower the salary on the market. This is not allowed by law. So this law also protects you from getting worse conditions in comparison with local employees (and this is probably what your employer tried to do to you).

Comment: @AndreySapegin I am not completely convinced. You're not getting anything, not even the right to stay in the country, let alone a job with better conditions. As I wrote, the law mostly protects local workers.

Comment: There are 2 types of checks that Arbeitsagentur can do. First check, is to prove that no locals are available for the position (so that foreigners do not make competition to locals). However, according to latest law changes, *this check should not be performed for IT positions* (https://www.anerkennung-in-deutschland.de/html/de/fachkraefteeinwanderungsgesetz.php). Second check is to prove that the conditions are not so bad, that only foreigners will agree with it. This indeed protects locals, but it also protects you from being discriminated. Your contract failed this second check.

Comment: @AndreySapegin I understand that, I still don't agree it “protects” you from anything and just claiming it does doesn't change anything. A law that would bump your salary or fine the company might be construed as a protection, not a law that leaves you with no work and no residence title. At the end of the day, you're still being “discriminated”, after all locals have a right to reside which you don't.

Comment: Try to think about this law as protecting all workers indifferent of their location or residence or citizenship. The employer is not allowed to "utilise" foreigners in badly manner in order to drop down the salaries for everybody (both locals and non-locals on the market). Try to find a better employer, reapply for the visa and I hope you will get it.

Comment: All I want to say is that the law is not against you personally, it is against lowering salaries for all workers.

Comment: By contrast, other measures could actually protect non-residents from discrimination, e.g. robust protections against low wages for everybody (Germany is particularly weak in that respect) or the end of residence titles tied to one specific job.